# Дано два массива заказов из разных систем.Необходимо привязать заказы друг к другу на основе имеющихся данных

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULSZG.jpg

Как это сделать на vuejs?И Какие ключи нужно брать?

Comment: не нашел в имеющихся данных ничего общего

Answer (score 1):

При помощи синтаксиса [***spread*** `(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) можно объединить два итерируемых объекта в один

```js
let example = {
  Bankai: 'Sendonzakura Kagayoshi',
  NewBankai: 'Conjiki Aisogizjo'
}
let ichigo = {
  bankai: 'tensa zangetsu'
}
const newExapmle = { ...ichigo,
  ...example
}
console.log(newExapmle);
```